# (Why) does .forEach() mutate vuex state?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I grab two sets of balances from my vuex state and merge them into a new array of entries.
why is an error thrown when i iterate over my **copies** of the vuex state? am i missing something?

`.filter()` returns a new array, so `coins` is not connected to the $state any more.

I'm not mutating the vuex state, but my copies of it. still i'm warned to not mutate vuex store outside of mutations.

this would make sense, if those assignments were actual *references* to the vuex store, but they're not (or are they??). I've tried to understand what's wrong here, but i can't understand what's wrong here. i hope you guys can help. thanks!

```
filteredItems() {
      let coins = this.$store.state.wallet.balances.filter(( item ) => this.getCoinPropertiesByTicker(item.ticker).staking_available);
      const stakingCoins = this.$store.state.wallet.stakingBalances;
->    coins.forEach((coin) => {     // error happening here
        const stakingCoin = stakingCoins.user.stats.find((name) => name.ticker === coin.ticker)
        if (stakingCoin) {
          coin.totalAmount = {
            amt: new BigNumber(stakingCoin.balance).decimalPlaces(8).toString(),
            usd: new BigNumber(stakingCoin.balance_usd).decimalPlaces(2).toString()
          }
        }
      return coins
      }



[Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "function () { return this._data.$$state }": "Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers."

(found in <Root>)


vue.esm.js?a026:1897 Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.
    at assert (vuex.esm.js?2f62:90)
    at Vue.store._vm.$watch.deep (vuex.esm.js?2f62:793)
    at Watcher.run (vue.esm.js?a026:4577)
    at Watcher.update (vue.esm.js?a026:4551)
    at Dep.notify (vue.esm.js?a026:739)
    at Object.reactiveSetter [as amountStaked30] (vue.esm.js?a026:1064)
    at eval (Staking.vue?3a4a:134)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at VueComponent.filteredItems (Staking.vue?3a4a:115)
    at Watcher.get (vue.esm.js?a026:4488)
```

Comment: Objects in your array are passed by reference: when you filter an array, it creates a new instance of the array, but the objects contained inside it are all pointing to the same objects in the original array.

Comment: error happening here `coin.totalAmount = {`, as says in the message *do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers*, make a copy of the store, mutate the values and then commit back, or use a handler in store

Comment: Here is an article which explains how pointers work and how to circumvent them with deep cloning. Libraries like Lodash make this easier. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/js-deep-cloning-javascript-objects

Comment: Yeah, you need to be using mutations and not directly filtering your store. Or, I think you might be able to mapState https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper if you want to avoid extra boilerplate.

Comment: @Ahmed Jaouadi splice does the same thing as filter: it creates a shallow copy of the array. OP needs to look at cloning the array of objects deeply.

Answer (score 0):

As others have posted (and i didn't know), the actual items **inside** the array are references to the store, even after assigning it to a variable.

in my case, i did `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$store.state.wallet.balances)).filter(( item ) => this.getCoinPropertiesByTicker(item.ticker).staking_available)`, which creates a deep copy, and now the error is gone.

Thanks!